# PhpStorm Debugging Project with Subdomains

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am searching for a solution for an issue which I assume a lot of you have: Debugging with PhpStorm several Subdomains.

Our project lives in an environment where we have several country/language bases country subdomains. e.G.: `france.myproject.com`, `spain.myproject.com`, `uk.myproject.com`, etc.

Our local testing environment tries to stick to that, so locally we got something similar. Like `fr.myproject.dev`, `es.myproject.dev`, etc.

When debugging with PhpStorm - as of now - I have to go to "Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers" and add a server with path mappings for each subdomain and port. So I end up creating an entry for each, which looks like...

```
fr.myproject.dev (http)
fr.myproject.dev (https)
es.myproject.dev (http)
es.myproject.dev (https)
```

etc...
I tried using a `*` as wildcard for the subdomain. But that didn't work out. I tried using only domain `myproject.dev` - didn't work out either.

Has anyone solved this problem by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, IDE needs such domain/port mappings to know what project/mapping to use (as you have an option to ignore connections from unregistered server configurations). Maybe you can report (in your PHP code or at web server level) single server name instead of different domains for each -- this way only 2 configs would be needed (for HTTP & HTTPS). AFAIK IDE checks the value of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` (no 100% but very likely). Similar with the port number... Have a look (try changing it for an entry that is already configured) and see if it works (should ask for setup).

Answer (score 0):

It's not wildcard support, but I've found that many settings - **including path mappings** - can be added to a deployment, which can be shared between servers.

If you visit *Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment*, you can create an "In Place" deployment in your web root. From there, you can specify mappings.

When you first debug using one of your `.myproject.dev` subdomains, you can select *Import mappings from deployment*, which will automatically use the mappings you defined earlier.